# Show that $∀x∃yRxy ⊢ ∃zRf(a)z$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I'm very logic noob.

I'm having trouble deciphering what this means.

What I've got is "For all $x$, there exists some $y$ such that $x$ Respects (R) $y$ ~something~ there exists some $z$ such that $f(a)$ Respects (R) $z$"

I know that ⊢ means that $B$ is provable from $A$ but I'm not even sure what $A$ and $B$ are in this case.

Help.

Comment: $A$ is the statement $\forall x\exists y~Rxy$ and $B$ is the statement $\exists z~Rf(a)z$.  You are required to show $B$ is derivable from $A$ using your proof system.   So what *is* your proof system?

Comment: @GrahamKemp Thank you that makes a lot of sense. I believe we need to prove it by exhausting all the cases or prove it false by finding an example that does not satisfy the statement.

Comment: That would be the process for *semantic entailment*, which uses the symbol $\vDash$.  *Syntactic entailment*, indicated by the $\vdash$ symbol, is a process for proof of logical entailment by using *axiom schema* and *rules of inference* and such.  Double check which your source requires.

Comment: So is " 'There exists some z such that f(a) respects z' is provable from 'For all x there exists some y such that x respects y' " the correct interpretation of this? E: Source doesn't call for any specific process just proving valid or invalid.

Comment: Well, if that is the only method you've been taught (so far) then you must go with it.  Include what you have tried in your post.

Comment: $f(a)$ is a *term* i.e. a "name" for an object. Thus, if we know that for **every** object $x$ there is an $y$ such that $y$ is $R$-related to $x$, for sure there will be a $z$ that is $R$-related also to the "specific" object $F(a)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So can I say that x is the domain, y is the co-domain. Thus, z is some x and f(a) is the co-domain of that x?

Answer (score 4):

Obviously, we have to assume that the *constant* symbol $a$ and the *function* symbol $f$ are part of the [language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Formation_rules).

This means that $f(a)$ is a [term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Terms).

Thus, it is enough to apply [Universal Instantiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_instantiation) rule (aka $(\forall \text E)$ ) : $\forall x \varphi \vdash \varphi [x/t]$, with term $f(a)$ as $t$, to get from $∀x∃y \ R(x,y)$ the conclusion :

> $∃y \ R(f(a),y)$.

The change of bound variable is straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

It's worthwhile to point out that the solution has nothing to do with function domain and codomain as you expressed confusions in your last comment, which means you still haven't *completely* understood the problem. By the way completeness is a very demanded quality in logic before compactness (completeness theorem, incompleteness theorems, etc). As a side inspirational note from philosophy, completeness in ancient Sanskrit and Pali is called Pāramitā, which also means perfection and many ancient philosophical and religious classics' titles end in Pāramitā or Prajñāpāramitā.

You worried about domain/codomain because you were only aware at the usual set-theoretic semantic level regarding the definitions of functions, relations, etc. But for this problem as the previous answer rightly pointed out, f(a) is just a first order logic (FOL) concept called *constant term* (of course f itself is another FOL concept called function symbol) to intentionally conflate you with set-theoretic function. Since the question asked already presented f(a) meaning it actually exists and you never need to doubt its soundness, and all later derivation are only syntactic entailment (⊢). Finally via semantic meaning from set theory, any function can be changed to an equivalent relation (not vice versa). So your claim
in your last comment is incorrect, R is a binary relation symbol in FOL which we can only talk about it's *satisfied* or not by evaluation of its two arguments, it doesn't make sense to talk about its domain/codomain. A relation can always be mentally treated as a default function at the set theory meta-level (though not a valid concept at the FOL logic level) assuming its codomain is some truth object ranging only 2 distinct values such as the usual bits {0, 1}, but be careful truth value in such codomain is not normal grounded object in the official domain of discourse within FOL (thus cannot be quantified and hardly useful). Only in higher order logics you're allowed to ground predicate relations directly and range over a family of possible relations so that we can express something like if two objects share two such and such properties then they are the same object.

Hope this can *completely* dissolve your unanswered lingering confusion...